# How to draw a circle in gimp?

Tags: gimp

[image]

[image]

The requirement is very simple. Just draw a red bordered circle in a specific position.

Comment: https://alvinalexander.com/gimp/gimp-how-to-create-draw-circle-in-gimp-tutorial, http://dpod.kakelbont.ca/2012/06/14/how-to-draw-a-circle-in-gimp-seriously/

Comment: @muru 2nd link solution is short and helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Excellent, you can post an answer describing which one worked, and accept it later.

Comment: Actually a pretty dirty solution

Answer (score 8):

For a clean result (uniform thickness, smooth and clean edges):

1. Use the Ellipse select tool to make a selection
2. `Select>To path`
3. `Select>None` (otherwise step #4 will only create half of the line)
4. `Edit>Stroke path` in "Line" mode

[image]

### Simplifications

- If you do several circles, you can do a selection with several circles in step 1 (shift click for additional circles), and execute steps 2-4 only once.
- For thin lines (3px or less); you can replace steps 2-4 by a `Edit>Stroke selection` (but this is ugly on tick lines)
- You can of course do both together (many thin circles)

Comment: So intuitive ...

Comment: This post more specifically addresses why conversion to path might produce bette results: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69445/gimp-jagged-borders